# Type-ahead Eclipse suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse

I just updated to a new version of Eclipse. When I selected the workspace, the installer mentioned something about rebuilding the workspace to make it compatible.

After the update, I realized that the Type-ahead suggestions aren't working anymore.

Example: I want to find a variable named testFailed, so I used to type something like "tef" and the search engine would find the "f" character ahead.

Now I have to type sequentially "testf" to find the variable.

I already tried to change the configurations in Window > Preferences > Editor, but no success.

The type-ahead was really helpful to me.

Do someone knows if it's an update problem or there is a configuration to make it happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is in _Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist_ the checkbox _Show substring matches_ checked? Probably you face this issue because of the removal of Code Recommenders in Eclipse 2018-12.

Comment: Yes, the substring matches was checked. But the second part of your answer solved my problem, I manually installed the Code Recommenders plugin, when eclipse restarted it was asked to update some other things. Now it's working! Thank you very much!